# setting up a tf for SICK Laser Scanner PLS101-312

Tags: ros, base-laser, sick, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working with a 2d laser scanner (PLS101-312). There are no registered drivers available for this device in the ROS repositories. however, following this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/61600/sick-scanner-pls200-113/), I was able to find a fork on git [here](https://github.com/hawesie/laser_drivers/tree/master/sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper), which works pretty fine on the device I am working on. I could also see the stream of laser data using `$ rostopic echo /scan`

My question here is, How can I view the laser scan data on rviz? When tried the /scan topic on rviz, I get an error saying that the frame for laser_scanner cannot be /world, the [example here](http://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms) shows that it is being set to a base_laser. how can I do the same? I am aware that, there should be a tf for my laser_scanner, what would be the simplest way of setting up a tf for the laser, just for testing the laser scanner output? please suggest, some Ideas.

Thanks again,

Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194513/setting-up-a-tf-for-sick-laser-scanner-pls101-312/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, Just for the record. the steps I followed to setup the SICK PLS 101-312 scanner on ROS groovy are:

1. create a workspace and clone the pls_wrapper into this directory as shown below.

   `$ mkdir ~/sickplsws/src;cd ~/sickplsws/src; sudo git clone https://github.com/hawesie/laser_drivers.git`
2. now to build this source code, with `rosmake`.
3. Start your ros master in a new terminal `$ roscore` and in the old terminal where you sourced the catkin package, type the below command
   `$ rosrun sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper sick_pls_wrapper _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=38400` (Note: you should be able to tab autofill after you type sicktoolbox_ ... if not, check if you have built the source code properly or not). This command will take a while (assuming that you are connecting the laser at /dev/ttyUSB0 and with a baud of 38400).
4. Now in a new terminal type `$ rostopic echo /scan`, if you have done everything right you should a get stream of serial data being pushed into your PC terminal. Now the important part, CTRL+C, scroll up in the same screen and find out what header message you are getting in the data stream you received serially. Note down what is against the

> Frame : laser_xx
> 5. in another terminal, type `$ rosrun rviz rviz`, click Add-> laser scanner and under the laser scanner find the topic and make it as /scan. if you get an error now, just make the global fixed_frame as ***laser_xx*** or to whatever you find from step 4.

And you should be able to see the data spread on the 2D plane of RVIZ.

Cheers,

---

Originally posted by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) with karma: 246 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hipystix](https://answers.ros.org/users/28583/hipystix/) on 2016-11-20**:
Just wanted to let you know that your steps worked for me.  I did have to make one change as noted [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/230106/error-while-installing-sick-lidar-cmatlab-toolbox/).  I'm using Kinetic.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to see the laser data, just type in whatever frame is in the scan message into fixed_frame in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-10-08**:
Hi, the node has only one topic being published (/scan) , there is no frame associated with the laser. Also using any random frame, throws up an error on rviz.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-08**:
The laser message will have some frame. use that in rviz. The name doesn't matter, if the laser isn't mounted to anything.